# If $e^{(k)} = (0,0,\ldots,1,0,0,\ldots)$ then show that $S = \{e^{(k)}: k\ge 1\}$ is a closed subset of $\ell^1$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I saw this problem on MathSE before, and while the proofs given as answers look good - I'm unable to carry forward my own attempts.

> If $e^{(k)} = (0,0,\ldots,1,0,0,\ldots)$ with $1$ in the $k$th position, then show that $S = \{e^{(k)}: k\ge 1\}$ is a closed subset of $\ell^1$.

**My work:**

1. To show that $S\subset \ell^1$ is closed, we can show that $\ell^1\setminus S$ is **open**. In other words, for an arbitrary sequence $x\in\ell^1$ we must find $r$ so that $B(x,r)\subset \ell^1\setminus S$. Here, $B(x,r) = \{y\in\ell^1: \|x-y\|_1 = \sum_{i\ge 1}|x_i-y_i| < r\}$. What do I do next?
2. *Another way* I thought was to use the following proposition:
   $F$ is closed **iff** if $B(x,\epsilon)\cap F\neq\varnothing$ for every $\epsilon>0$, then $x\in F$. Suppose now for some $x\in\ell^1$, $\forall\epsilon > 0\ (B(x,\epsilon)\cap S\neq\varnothing)$. In other words, $\exists e^{(k)}\in S$ s.t. $$\sum_{i\ge 1} |x_i-e^{(k)}_i| = |x_k-1| +\sum_{i\ge 1,i\ne k}|x_i| < \epsilon, \text{ for all }\epsilon > 0$$ Now how does one conclude that $x\in S$?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Let me propose an easier way : Let $(e_n)$ a convergent sequence of $S$. Prove there is $N\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $e_n=e_N$ for all $n\geq N$.

Comment: what is $e$ ? I took,$(e_n)$ a sequence of $S$. How does it help ? Don't you know that in metric spaces, a set is closed sets $\iff$ it's sequentially closed ?

Comment: I do know that - yes! Another question, $e_n$ is convergent w.r.t. what metric? The one induced by $\ell^1$ itself, I am assuming. Also, the $\ell_1$ norm of all elements of $S$ is exactly $1$ - would that help in proving what you stated?

Comment: Of course, $(e_n)$ is convergent w.r.t. to $\ell^1$ norm. The fact that $e_n$ has norm 1 for all $n$ is indeed important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try to complete your attempt 1:

**Idea**: We would *want* to pick something like $r = \displaystyle\min_{k \in \Bbb N}d(x^{(k)}, x)$ but the problem is that $\min$ does not make sense and $\inf$ might turn out to be $0$. Thus, we will first show that after a stage, $d(x^{(k)}, x)$ can be explicitly bounded below, by say, $1/2$. In that case, we only have to take $\min$ over a finite range. (This is similar to how we show that a convergent sequence is bounded.)

---

Let us pick $x \in \ell^1 \setminus S.$ Note that $x \in \ell^1$ implies that $|x_k|$ is eventually strictly less than $1/2$. (Since $x_n \to 0.$)

Suppose that this happens after $k = N$. This means that $$d(e^{(m)}, x) \ge |1 - x_m| \ge |1-|x_m|| > \frac{1}{2}$$
for $m > N$.

Intuitively, this means that $e^{(k)}$ after $k = N$ are at least distance $1/2$ away. Thus, choosing $$r = \min\left\{d(x, e^{(1)}), \ldots, d(x, e^{(N)}), \frac12\right\} > 0$$
does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\|e^{(n)} - e^{(m)}\|_1 = 2 \text{ whenever } n \neq m$$

This implies that there is no convergent sequence from $S$ converging to some $x \in \ell^1 \setminus S$ because then we would have points from $S$ getting arbitarily close to each other (triangle inequality via limit...) and we just saw that this does not happen. So $S$ is closed and discrete.